# how to use substring-after function?

Tags: xml

```
<rpc-reply xmlns:junos="http://xml.juniper.net/junos/12.1X46/junos">
<multi-routing-engine-results>

    <multi-routing-engine-item>

        <re-name>node0</re-name>

        <environment-information xmlns="http://xml.juniper.net/junos/12.1X46/junos-chassis">
            <environment-item>
                <name>Routing Engine</name>
                <class>Temp</class>
                <status>OK</status>
                <temperature junos:celsius="58">58 degrees C / 136 degrees F</temperature>
            </environment-item>
            <environment-item>
                <name>Routing Engine CPU</name>
                <status>Absent</status>
            </environment-item>
            <environment-item>
                <name>Power Supply 0</name>
                <class>Power</class>
                <status>OK</status>
            </environment-item>
        </environment-information>
    </multi-routing-engine-item>

    <multi-routing-engine-item>

        <re-name>node1</re-name>

        <environment-information xmlns="http://xml.juniper.net/junos/12.1X46/junos-chassis">
            <environment-item>
                <name>Routing Engine</name>
                <class>Temp</class>
                <status>OK</status>
                <temperature junos:celsius="57">57 degrees C / 134 degrees F</temperature>
            </environment-item>
            <environment-item>
                <name>Routing Engine CPU</name>
                <status>Absent</status>
            </environment-item>
            <environment-item>
                <name>Power Supply 0</name>
                <class>Power</class>
                <status>OK</status>
            </environment-item>
        </environment-information>
    </multi-routing-engine-item>

</multi-routing-engine-results>
<cli>
    <banner>{primary:node0}[edit]</banner>
</cli>
```

/rpc-reply//multi-routing-engine-item[number(substring(substring-after(/rpc-reply/cli/banner/text(),"node"),1,1))+1]//environment-item[1]/name

/rpc-reply//multi-routing-engine-item[1]//environment-item[1]/name

Can I get "Routing Engine" ?

thanks in advance !!

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: from xml tester